# Way to check if dynamic predicate contains a value

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

Very new to Prolog.
Goal is to check if dynamic predicate contains a specific value.
Doing it in the following way but does not work:

```
:- dynamic storage/1. 

not(member(Z,storage)), // checking if Z is already a member of storage - this does not work. 
assert(storage(Z)). // asserting Z if above is true
```

Could you please explain how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
:- dynamic storage/1. 

append_to_database_but_only_once(Z) :- 
   must_be(nonvar,Z),      % Z must be bound variable (an actual value)
   \+ storage(Z),          % If "storage(Z)" is true already, fail!
   assertz(storage(Z)).    % ...otherwise append to the database
```

And so:

```
?- append_to_database_but_only_once(foo).
true.

?- storage(X).
X = foo.

?- append_to_database_but_only_once(foo).
false.
```

Note that you don't need to query any datastructure or list with `member/2`. With `assertz/1`, you are changing the Prolog database itself! So afterwards you just need to perform the corresponding query, `storage(Z)`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for explaining